# laravel if statement not working

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement

can anyone please tell me why when the results are equal then it echo's out the response, but when the results are false then it shows a blank page. I am sure i have gone wrong somewhere.

```
if(isset($_GET['EX1']) && $_GET['EX2'] != ""){

        $Email = $_GET['EX1'];
        $Password = $_GET['EX2'];

        $userDetails = DB::table('applicants')
            ->where('Email', '=', $Email)
            ->where('Password','=', $Password)
            ->get();

        if($Email = $userDetails[0]->Email && $Password = $userDetails[0]->Password){

            echo 'Both are the same ';

        }else{

            echo 'Not the same';

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using this in a route or controller?

Comment: Why are you not using `Request`?

Comment: If you're just going to look for the first user in the array, you can use `first()` instead of `get()`. Then you can drop the `[0]` from your userDetails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work!

```
public function myfunction(Request $request) {
    if(!empty($request->EX1) && !empty($request->EX2)){

        $Email = $request->EX1;
        $Password = $request->EX2;

        $userDetails = DB::table('applicants')
            ->where('Email', '=', $Email)
            ->where('Password','=', $Password)
            ->get();

        if($Email == $userDetails[0]->Email && $Password == $userDetails[0]->Password){

            return 'Both are the same ';

        }else{

            return 'Not the same';

        }
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
```

Btw, you need to change `if(.... = ....)` to `if(.... == ....)`. `=` is for assigning values and `==` is for comparing values.

Hope this works!

Answer (score 2):

```
if($Email = $userDetails[0]->Email && $Password = $userDetails[0]->Password){
```

should be

```
if($Email == $userDetails[0]->Email && $Password == $userDetails[0]->Password){
```

You're using assignment `=` instead of comparison `==` which will always return `true`